# replicating mouse motion using ajax

Tags: ajax

I want to implement an application on my website where once the users are connected, they share a text editor. If one user enters anything on
the text editor available on his screen, the same text appears on the second user’s
screen at the same coordinates.

Same thing goes for the other user. Also there would be pointer shaped images on both user’s screens to represent mouse pointers.
When user A moves his mouse pointer, the image on user B’s screen should be
moved according to the movement of user A’s mouse and similarly, when user B
moves his mouse, the image on user A’s screen should be moved accordingly.

The problem is I am using database to store the coordinates of each user. And this approach results in the a lot of lag and delay. What should I use in place of the database?? Please Help !

Comment: The problem really isn't the database, but rather connection speed. I don't see a method like this working, unless your working on the same LAN.

Comment: Have you tried Google docs with shared documents. Basically you have to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to request the updates but push them to your clients: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29 . This reduces the delay between an update from your client to the server and other clients again checking for updates.

Answer (score 0):

how abt using Redis : http://code.google.com/p/redis/

an example of a similar collaborative text editor using this : http://www.web2media.net/laktek/2010/05/25/real-time-collaborative-editing-with-websockets-node-js-redis/